# how to put system tools into gnome3 panel

Tags: gnome, configuration, desktop-environments, panel

I'm sure it has been asked before, but I cannot find the solution.
I started using Gnome3, and everything is great. But, system tools has been put in Applications. I want System to be a top level menu?

I tried tooling around in the Configuration editor, but I could not figure it out. 
I read this:[How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop)
but it doesn’t take care of the system menu.

Then I start reading the free-desktop pages about basedir specifications but none of it was helpful.

How, can I get my system menu back where it belongs. I mean that it belongs next to the places menu, and not under applications. Mate has it, but mate breaks when I install cheese.

So, where are the panel menus configured? What file do i need to edit to get this looking right?

The system menu I refer to is high lighted Here:
I want it to reside to the right of "Places"
[image: The system menu I reffer to is high lighted Here:]

Comment: I can't understand the question --- which application menu are you referring to? Can you add a screenshot? In my Gnome3 I have no application menu --- hot corner and type the command name.